# is there any specific permssion in Azure devops for code review?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, devops-services

i want to give a person a permission for code review purpose only (no other permission).Is there any such permission in Azure DevOps?
Anyone please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such permission in Azure Devops. The only option is to limit the person permission as much as possible, which is denying all the other permissions and only allow contribute to pull requests. You can check out below steps:

1,  Add user to your organization with basic access.

Go to **Organization** settings->**Security**->**Permission**->**Users**->**Select** the user and deny All his permission.

2,Add this user to the Readers group of your Project

Go to the **project settings**->**Permissions**->Select **Readers** group->**Add** this user

3,Set the user's permissions for your Project.

Go to the **project settings**->**Permissions**->**Users**->**Select** this user-> **Deny** all the permissions except **View project-level information**.

[image]

4, Setting user's permissions for Repos.

Go to the **project settings**->**Repos**->**Repositories**->**Select** the repo(Or Click the **Permissions** tab under **All Repositories** to set the permissions for all repos)->**Permissions**->**Search** for the user in the search bar->Only allow **Contribute to pull requests** and **Read** permissions for this user

[image]
[image]

5, Set permissions for Pipeline.

Go your **project portal**->**Pipelines**->Click the **3dots**->**Manager Security**

[image]

**Search** for the User in the Search bar->change his permission of **view builds and view build pipeline** to Deny

[image]

6,Set permission for Release.

Go your **project portal**->**Releases**-> Click the **3dots**->**Security**
[image]

**Search** for the User in the Search bar->change his permission of **view releases and view release pipeline** to Deny

[image]

Even so the personal's permission cannot be limited to only review code entirely. He can have the read permission to Overview and Artifacts.

Hope above helps!